# Why can't vue find variable in loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm struggling to develop a simple component and use it inside a loop:

```html
<template id="measurement">
    <tr class="d-flex">
    </tr>
</template>
```

```js
Vue.component('measurement', {
    template: '#measurement',
    props: {
        name: String,
        data: Object,
        val: String,
    },
});
```

This is obviously not functional yet but already fails:

```html
<table v-for="(m, idx) in sortedMeters">
    <measurement v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
</table>
```

gives `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: m` inside view. For a strange reason the same thing works, i.e. without error, in a paragraph:

```html
<p v-for="(m, idx) in sortedMeters">
    <measurement v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
</p>
```

What causes the variable to be not found?

PS.: here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andig2/u47gh3w1/. It shows a different error as soon as the `table` is included.

**Update** It is intended that the loop produces multiple tables. Rows per table will be created by multiple `measurement`s

Comment: While I don't know the answer to your question (I'm also puzzled by it), checking the resulting HTML shows that you are creating two tables (each for iteration creates one `table` element) which would each contain one `tr` if this would work. Aren't you intending to loop the `tr` element? But even looping on the `tr` element causes the error...

Comment: Thats actually intended- in the end I‘ll need multiple tables for the use case.

Comment: Then the first half of my answer should answer your question. Well, not answer it, but give you a solution, because I have no idea why yours doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** Before Vue is passed the DOM template, the browser is hoisting `<measurement v-bind:name="i" v-bind:data="m">` outside the `<table>` (outside `v-for` context), leading to the errors in Vue. This is a known [caveat of DOM template parsing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats).

---

The [HTML spec requires the `<table>` contain only specific child elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element):

- `<caption>`
- `<colgroup>`
- `<thead>`
- `<tbody>`
- `<tr>`
- `<tfoot>`
- `<script>` or `<template>` intermixed with above

Similarly, the [content model of `<tr>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element) is:

- `<td>`
- `<th>`
- `<script>` or `<template>` intermixed with above

The DOM parser of compliant browsers automatically hoists disallowed elements – such as `<measurement>` – outside the table. This happens *before* the scripting stage (before Vue even gets to see it).

For instance, this markup:

```html
<table>
  <tr v-for="(m,i) in obj">
    <measurement v-bind:name="i" v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
  </tr>
</table>
```

...becomes this after DOM parsing (before any scripting):

```html
<measurement v-bind:name="i" v-bind:data="m"></measurement> <!-- hoisted outside v-for -->
<table>
  <tr v-for="(m,i) in obj">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Notice how `i` and `m` are then outside the context of the `v-for` loop, which results in Vue runtime errors about `i` and `m` not defined (unless by chance your component coincidentally declared them already). `m` was intended to be bound to `<measurement>`'s `data` prop, but since that failed, `data` is simply its initial value (also `undefined`), causing the rendering of `{{data.value}}` to fail with `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"`.

To demonstrate hoisting without these runtime errors and without Vue, run the code snippet below:

```html
<table style="border: solid green">
  <tr>
    <div>1. hoisted outside</div>
    <td>3. inside table</td>
    2. also hoisted outside
  </tr>
</table>
```

...then inspect the result in your browser's DevTools, which should look like this:

```html
<div>1. hoisted outside</div>
2. also hoisted outside
<table style="border: solid green">
  <tr>
    <td>3. inside table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Solution 1: Use `<tr is="measurement">`

If you prefer DOM templates, you could use the [`is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/is) attribute on a `<tr>` to specify `measurement` as the type (as suggested by the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats) and by another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59698160/6277151)). This first requires the `<measurement>` template use `<td>` or `<th>` as a container element inside `<tr>` to be valid HTML:

```html
<template id="measurement">
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}} -> {{data.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <table v-for="(m,i) in sortedMeters">
    <tr is="measurement" v-bind:name="i" v-bind:data="m" v-bind:key="i"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('measurement', {
  template: '#measurement',
  props: {
    name: String,
    data: Object
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sortedMeters: {
      apple: {value: 100},
      banana: {value: 200}
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<template id="measurement">
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}} -> {{data.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <table v-for="(m,i) in sortedMeters">
    <tr is="measurement" v-bind:name="i" v-bind:data="m" v-bind:key="i"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

### Solution 2: Wrap `<table>` in component

If you prefer DOM templates, you could use a wrapper component for `<table>`, which would be able to contain `<measurement>` without the hoisting caveat.

```js
Vue.component('my-table', {
  template: `<table><slot/></table>`
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <my-table v-for="(m, i) in sortedMeters">
    <measurement v-bind:name="i" v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
  </my-table>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('measurement', {
  template: '#measurement',
  props: {
    name: String,
    data: Object
  }
})

Vue.component('my-table', {
  template: `<table><slot/></table>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sortedMeters: {
      apple: {value: 100},
      banana: {value: 200}
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<template id="measurement">
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}} -> {{data.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <my-table v-for="(m, i) in sortedMeters">
    <measurement v-bind:name="i" v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
  </my-table>
</div>
```

### Solution 3: Move `<table>` markup into template string

You could move the entire `<table>` into a component's template string, where the DOM template caveats could be avoided. *Similarly, you could move the `<table>` into a [single file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), but I assume you have a significant need for DOM templates instead.*

```js
Vue.component('my-table', {
  template: `<div>
    <table v-for="(m, idx) in sortedMeters">
      <measurement v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
    </table>
  </div>`,
  props: {
    sortedMeters: Object
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <my-table v-bind:sorted-meters="sortedMeters"></my-table>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('measurement', {
  template: '#measurement',
  props: {
    name: String,
    data: Object
  }
})

Vue.component('my-table', {
  template: `<div>
    <table v-for="(m,i) in sortedMeters">
      <measurement v-bind:name="i" v-bind:data="m" v-bind:key="i"></measurement>
    </table>
  </div>`,
  props: {
    sortedMeters: Object
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sortedMeters: {
      apple: {value: 100},
      banana: {value: 200}
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<template id="measurement">
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}} -> {{data.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <my-table :sorted-meters="sortedMeters"></my-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you replace

```
<table v-for="(m, idx) in sortedMeters">
  <measurement v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
</table>
```

with

```
<template v-for="(m, idx) in sortedMeters">
  <table>
    <measurement v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
  </table>
</template>
```

You'll end up with working code.

But you'll most likely want to use

```
<table>
  <template v-for="(m, idx) in sortedMeters">
    <measurement v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
  </template>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
  <measurement v-for="(m, idx) in sortedMeters" v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
</table>
```

Comment: I can confirm that wrapping the table with template works. However- i can use the loop on the table just fine as long as I don't add the child component and instead do the tr's html manually. It remains a mystery why that fails.

Comment: Wrapping the table in `<template>` works only because its contents are inert (unparsed by the DOM parser until invoked by JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've missing `<td>` inside `<tr>`. Without it your component produces invalid html markup and extracts "slot" data outside `<tr>` causing error.

Your template should looks like:

```html
<template id="measurement">
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}} -> {{data.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

You also need to move `v-for` to `measurement`:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr is="measurement" v-for="(m,index) in obj" :key="index" v-bind:name="index" v-bind:data="m"></measurement>
</table>
```

You can use `is` attribute to set component name.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cyaj0ukh/

Comment: Are you sure it's an invalid HTML-thing? I've changed his fiddle to have proper HTML code but even that fails. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hpc9Lmjr/

Comment: Reached the same conclusing. I need multiple tables, but even with proper html it fails.

Comment: @andig This answer is essentially correct about the question's HTML being invalid (+1), although the explanation is somewhat incomplete IMO.